# UITabBar with UINavigationController in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've currently got a UITabBar with 5 screens calling UIViews. That part works fine but I want to put in a UINavigationController in a couple of them. I have found a few tutorials that work fine but all of them implement it in IB and I want to avoid that if possible.

I'm lost as to where to implement the UINavigationController, should I do it in the App Delegate with the UITabBar and call the navigation controller from the UIView or should I create it in the UIView class?

I've tried about 8 different ways and always ends up with either the Navbar not working, no nav bar at all or the app crashing.

Currently I create the tab bar like this:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
ScreenA *screenA = [[ScreenA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenA" bundle:nil];
//more here
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:screenA, ...., nil];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

And in the initWithNibName I have this:

```
self.title = @"Screen A";
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, do it like this...

    `tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];`

```
searchTableViewController = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *searchTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchTableViewController] autorelease];
[searchTableViewController release];                                                              

searchMapViewController = [[SearchMapViewController alloc] init];   
UINavigationController *mapTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchMapViewController] autorelease];
[searchMapViewController release];                                                    


tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchTableNavController, mapTableNavController, nil];
```

Comment: Whats annoying about this is I should of know it, I used it in another App of mine :( *facepalm*

Comment: @Andiih: in this way, I don't succeed in naming the navbar and the tab bar item with two different names. Is there a way to do that?